# outlook mail object bcc

Tags: c#, outlook

```
//Create the session.
Outlook.Application application = new Outlook.Application();
//Create the session.                        
Outlook.MailItem mail = application.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem) as Outlook.MailItem;
//create the receipents object
Outlook.Recipients objOutlookRecip = mail.Recipients;

while (Recipients.Read())
{
    mail.Subject = Confirmations.GetString(2);
    mail.Body = Confirmations.GetString(4) + ("\r\n");        
    mail.Body = mail.Body + ("\r\n") + Confirmations.GetString(5) +     ("\r\n");
    mail.Body = mail.Body + ("\r\n") + Confirmations.GetString(6);
    mail.SentOnBehalfOfName = "user@email.com";
    mail.Recipients.Add(Recipients.GetString(8));
}
```

Does anyone know how i might be able to insert the email addresses into bcc instead of the current process in the to field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Outlook.Recipient recipBcc =
        mail.Recipients.Add(Recipients.GetString(8));
recipBcc.Type = (int)Outlook.OlMailRecipientType.olBCC;
```

check [OlMailRecipientType Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865653%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Comment: i tried to accept it right away but there is a 5 - 10 min point you have to wait before you accept :)